# Unable to start rails on port 80

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-12.04, rails

I am trying to learn Linux better but currently only have very limited experience - so please excuse my ignorance in this matter.

I am trying to start rails on port 80, and as another user by using

`sudo -u [user_name] bundle exec rails s --port=80 -e production`

but this is failing with

`eventmachine.rb:572:in 'start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError)`

Running `sudo netstat -anltp|grep :80` shows that port 80 is not open\listening.

I have tried the following, with limited success:

`sudo bundle exec rails s --port=80 -e production` works in starting the server on port 80, but not as the user I want,

`sudo -u [user_name] bundle exec rails s -e production` works in starting the server as the correct user, but not on the desired port.

I have temporarily set the user to be in the Administrators group as I have read that its required for ports < 1024, but that hasn't seemed to help either.

What else can I try?

Comment: To get around this limitation, I have just set the iptables to [redirect port 80 to port 3000](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2444737/826455), and am starting the rails server using the default port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start services on ports <1024 with root *user*. The group (administrator in your case) has nothing to do with it.

There are a few things you can do though. For example:

- User iptables to redirect the ports (configurable with root rights).
- If the program allows it or you have access to the code: start as root, bind(), then drop privileges.
- There is a utility called authbind that is meant for such cases, but I personally have never used it, so I cannot comment on how well it works.
- Use setcap to add privilege to your program.

Comment: The ultimate option would be to edit the kernel source code to remove the limit in the first place. See @Quandary's answer here: How can I run a server on Linux on port 80 as a normal user?: [http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user/660121#660121](http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user/660121#660121)